# Matrix Scatterplot with too many points

Tags: scatterplot

I am having some troubles with my scatterplot matrix.
I've already looked at the other similar questions but it seems that I still don't understand how to deal with the situation when you have too many points in your scatterplot matrix.
Here is my code below, Olten is a station in CH with 600 observations (going from january 1970 to december 2019) of 12 meteorological variables :

````
Olten = subset(OTL, time >= 197001 & time <= 201912)
pairs(~pva200m0+nto000m0+prestam0+tre200mx+tre200mn+tre200m0+rre150m0 +ure200m0 + ure200m0+su2000m0 +fkl010m0,data = Olten,main = "Scatterplot Matrix")```

my scatterplot matrix is really super dense with too many points, do you know how could I deal with that? 

Thank you very much
````